# How to save multiple graph in directory with unique file name in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to save multiple graph in a directory with unique file name. I have used `plt.savefig()` but its work only for one graph and also used below

***Edited***

```
path = 'C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Hiral_project_analysis/Output/'
plt.savefig(path + s_no + '_' + pdb_id  + ".png")
```

I have used above code to save the output file in directory with unique name... Now I am able to save the graphs but all graphs are blank (White Screen)...

Please help me

Comment: Please create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited my question with my script, please check

Comment: What is `candidates`?

Comment: Its a list and stored some data

Comment: @DavidG, I have again edited full script. please check

Comment: Can you please help me on above code? How to save multiple graphs in a directory with unique file name

Answer (score 3):

Accordign to documentation of [pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) first argument `fname` is not a path to a directory in which you want to save file, but

> A string containing a path to a filename, or a Python file-like object, or possibly some backend-dependent object such as PdfPages.

So you simply can use absolute path to a file as a first argument, eg.

```
path =  "C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Hiral_project_analysis/Outpit/" + protein_name + ".png"
plt.savefig(path)
```

Also I could not find in documentation other arguments you passed to `savefig` method i.e. `ext=".png", close=False, verbose=True`.

Comment: Dear Can you please explain with code? I want to save all graph in separate file with unique name in a directory

Comment: @user8825922: I have added 2-lines code sample. It should be enough to understand what to change in your code.

Comment: Thanks but that is also tried. I want to save all graphs in a output directory with unique file name. please suggest

Comment: You can use `protein_name` argument as a file name, so it would be: `path = "C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Hiral_project_analysis/Output/"+protein_name+".png"`

Comment: Getting error ` path = 'C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Hiral_project_analysis/Output/' + pro‌​tein_name + '.png'
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I am not going to write a code for you or find syntax errors in code snippets. I showed you everything you need to solve this issue and I believe you are smart enough to understand what you are doing in your code and why. If it is so you should also understand my suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of `savefig` has been described in the other answer. You need to provide the `path` **and** the filename to `savefig`. A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_and_savefig(fname):
    # create some random data
    x = np.random.randn(10)
    y = np.random.randn(10)

    plt.clf()  # clear the current figure
    plt.plot(x,y)

    path = "C:\Python34\\"
    plt.savefig(path + fname + ".png")

filenames = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]

for fname in filenames:
    create_and_savefig(fname)
```

Comment: Dear I used this `  path = 'C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Hiral_project_analysis/Output/'
plt.savefig(path + s_no + '_' + pdb_id  + ".png") ` and getting blank graph (white screen)

Comment: @user8825922 What are you plotting? What is `s_no` and `pdb_id`? As i've said before, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise i can't help you...