# How do I check the existing file with same name in the directory and use python to rename new files to save?

Tags: python, file, matplotlib

I am using `plt.savefig` to save a plot generated by matplotlib.pyplot, and I want to save my figure with different names each time I run the code. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save multiple graph in directory with unique file name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913137/how-to-save-multiple-graph-in-directory-with-unique-file-name-in-python)

Comment: Or see here: [Python: How to create a unique file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961509/python-how-to-create-a-unique-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to use the current time, if you don't save multiple files per second.

```
import datetime

ts = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H.%M.%S")
plt.savefig(f"figure-{ts}.png")
```